Unable to Capture Multiple Screens using PyQt5 Python
I'm trying to make a realtime data logger where I can select a portion of my screen using snipping tool kinda action and my code will log the changing values in that pixel range over time.
So far I can capture the text of my primary screen using the code below but even after I select the right screen from the total screens displayed the snipping tool always opens up on the primary screen.
I'm expecting this code to display the total screens the user have and display the snipping tool on the selected screen.
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PIL import ImageGrab
import numpy as np
import cv2
import pytesseract
import mss

class ScreenSelector(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Select Screen')
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Select a screen to capture:")
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        
        # Create a frame for displaying screens
        self.screen_frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self)
        self.screen_frame.setLayout(QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout())
        self.layout.addWidget(self.screen_frame)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        
        # Get available screens
        self.sct = mss.mss()
        self.monitors = self.sct.monitors

        # Display each screen's current content
        self.display_screens()

    def display_screens(self):
        """Display the current content of each screen as thumbnails."""
        for i, monitor in enumerate(self.monitors[1:], start=1):  # Skip the first monitor which is a total display
            screen_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
            screen_label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
            screen_label.setText(f"Screen {i}")

            # Capture the current content of the screen
            img = self.sct.grab(monitor)
            img_np = np.array(img)
            img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img_np, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2RGB)
            img_thumb = cv2.resize(img_rgb, (200, 150))  # Resize for thumbnail display

            # Convert to QImage for display
            height, width, channel = img_thumb.shape
            bytes_per_line = 3 * width
            q_img = QtGui.QImage(img_thumb.data, width, height, bytes_per_line, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)

            # Create a label for the thumbnail
            thumbnail_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
            thumbnail_label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(q_img))
            thumbnail_label.setFixedSize(200, 150)
            thumbnail_label.mousePressEvent = lambda event, index=i: self.select_screen(index)  # Connect click to selection

            # Add the screen label and thumbnail to the layout
            self.screen_frame.layout().addWidget(screen_label)
            self.screen_frame.layout().addWidget(thumbnail_label)

    def select_screen(self, index):
        """Proceed to snipping on the selected screen."""
        
        print("SELECTED SCREEN: ", self.monitors[index])
        
        # print(f"Selected screen: {index}")
        self.snipping_tool = SnippingTool(self.monitors[index])
        self.snipping_tool.show()  # Show snipping tool without full screen
        self.close()  # Close the screen selection window


class SnippingTool(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, monitor):
        super().__init__()
        self.monitor = monitor
        
        print("Selected Monitor: ", monitor)
        
        # Set geometry based on selected monitor
        self.setGeometry(monitor["left"], monitor["top"], monitor["width"], monitor["height"])
        self.begin = QtCore.QPoint()
        self.end = QtCore.QPoint()
        self.setWindowOpacity(0.3)
        QtWidgets.QApplication.setOverrideCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.CrossCursor))
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        print('Capture the screen...')
        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        qp.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor('black'), 3))
        qp.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(128, 128, 255, 128))
        qp.drawRect(QtCore.QRect(self.begin, self.end))

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.begin = event.pos()
        self.end = self.begin
        self.update()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.end = event.pos()
        self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.close()

        x1 = min(self.begin.x(), self.end.x())
        y1 = min(self.begin.y(), self.end.y())
        x2 = max(self.begin.x(), self.end.x())
        y2 = max(self.begin.y(), self.end.y())

        # Capture the selected area relative to the monitor coordinates
        img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(self.monitor["left"] + x1, self.monitor["top"] + y1,
                                    self.monitor["left"] + x2, self.monitor["top"] + y2))

        # Convert the captured image to OpenCV format
        img_cv = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(img), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

        # Use Tesseract to extract text from the captured image
        extracted_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img_cv)

        # Print the extracted text
        print("Extracted Text:\n", extracted_text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    screen_selector = ScreenSelector()
    screen_selector.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


What OS is this? Note that if it's on Linux, under certain circumstances (depending from the window manager), manual geometries may be ignored. Also, are you sure that the coordinates used for setGeometry() are correct for the given screen?

It's Windows and yes the coordinates are right, they are negative for the 2nd screen.
